# my proj is based on WSN.. its in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

i hav created a network.. i hav to calculate energy of all the nodes n this energy should get reduced as n when the node senses ..... plszz help me out in the energy part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your post is a bit confusing, maybe you should reformulate it as a question. If I understood correctly you are trying to simulate a Wireless Sensor Network in Matlab.

If you need handling of sensing events and reducing the energy (battery charge) of certain nodes, you can use Matlab classes and events.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/brk7uzk.html#brpeid9

If you need to calculate and minimize the energy usage and you know the positions of all nodes, you just need to calculate the minimum spanning tree, where the edge weights are the distances between the nodes.

There are lots of resources and algorithms on the net, e.g.

http://www.people.vcu.edu/~gasmerom/MAT131/mst.html

Comment: yes sir, i want to simulate a WSn... and plot graph for its performance...